# Github action triggered by workflow and manually

Tags: github-actions

i'm trying to build and deploy some code. i want to have 2 github workflows: build and deploy. the idea is to build some artifacts and deploy them automatically to dev environment for feature branches and stage for main branch on every push, but also to be able to deploy it to prod manually.

build workflow works as expected

build.yml:

```
name: build
on:
  push:
jobs:
  build-frontend:
    steps:
      - name: build
        run:
          .. do things here
      - name: save artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
```

and generates artifacts.

i was trying to make deploy workflow that is triggered:

- on `build` is completed with some default parameters.
- manually with more parameters

what i have tried:

```
name: deploy

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        description: 'Environment'
        required: true
        default: 'stage'
        options:
          - dev
          - stage
          - prod
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [build]
    types:
      - completed
```

and this workflow does not get triggered automatically. what am i missing?

any suggestions on a different approach are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Likely your issue is noted in [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run):

> This event will only trigger a workflow run if the workflow file is on the default branch

So if you run on a PR branch for example, that run doesn't trigger that workflow.

My suggestion would just to [change the event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_call) to `workflow_call`, define needed inputs, and call that job from the build.

e.g.

```yaml
name: build
on:
  push:
jobs:
  build-frontend:
    steps:
      - name: build
        run:
          .. do things here
      - name: save artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
  trigger-deploy:
    needs: [build-frontend]
    uses: ./workflows/deploy.yml
      with:
        environment: dev
```